# Is there a way to get Request Type (Get or Post) from the RestAssured Response?

Tags: rest-assured

I would like to know is there any built in option or custom option to get to know the type request from the RestAssured response object. i.e. By having response, I need to identify the response received is because of what type of request (POST or GET)?

Comment: From `Response` type, there is no way to get method of request.

Comment: I believe you have wrong architecture of your test.. HTTP is synchronous so that you send the request and then get response so that you always know which response is coming for which request. Even if you cannot pick that data from a request, you can work that around by keeping the proper state of your test system.

Comment: Hi Alexey R. I really understood that. I have an framework but which is not handling cookies as of now. I do not have control to modify any in the framework. But fortunately framework has the capability of adding custom codes which received the response object. So, I do not have any option with that response object as it executed for every request irrespective of GET or POST. My requirement is to execute some set of commands only for GET requests. I know by modifying framework this can be handled. But I would just like to know is there any possibility to do without modifying framework.